# Getting a property of another class in viewController.m

Tags: objective-c

I am working in a single view application.

Suppose,
I have a new Class called `BigCars`. In this new class, I have

```
@property (nonatomic) int carID;
```

Now if I go to viewController.h and create a property : @property (nonatomic,strong) BigCars *myBigCar;

Finally, I go to `viewController.m` and write `self.myBigCar.carID = 1234`;
Then if I

```
NSLog(@"%i", self.myBigCar.carID), I GET A 0 in the console.
```

Why?

(Assume I did the imports properly)

EDIT:

Creating a small game to help myself learn more about objective C development. Its a basic text game and the first page I have a label that contains a number. This number is the payers HP (Hit points). I have a character class called `Character.h` who has a

```
@property (nonatomic) int currentHealth;
```

In `viewController.h` I declared `@property (nonatomic,strong) *myCharacter;`-> I did this because I want to be able to use this object throughout the whole implementation file.

In `viewcontroller.m`, I want to set my label to this current health by writing :

```
// Create char
self.myCharacter.currentHealth = 89;
// Set labels and buttons
self.healthLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.myCharacter.currentHealth];
```

but for some reason, `self.myCharacter.currentHealth` does not set to 89 but is instead 0!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.myBigCar is nil because it was never instantiated, so all of its properties are also nil